# Leaflet custom markers for external GeoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, geojson

I'm new to Leaflet and I'm trying to style a external geoJSON feed with a customised marker.

I'm having trouble adding this to UOSensorsLayer in the code below. The official documentation is not too clear when it comes to the my implementation. I can only display the markers using the default leaflet blue marker.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet Map GeoJSON with Click Feature</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
<style>
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>

var UOSensors = $.ajax({
    url:"http://uoweb1.ncl.ac.uk/api/v1/sensors.geojson?api_key=j5wze84qf82y23luzkboejai2tqcdiqtpmu5swbq46r6s1cqtc86zhkctkbxf6chx8lqrxficjqt00kvwioukj81av",
    dataType: "json",
    success: console.log("Urban Observatory Sensor data successfully loaded."),
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.statusText)
    }
})
// Specify that this code should run once the data request is complete
$.when(UOSensors).done(function() {

var map = L.map('map');

cartodbAttribution = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>';

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYW5keXByb2N0b3IiLCJhIjoiY2o2amZqODVyMTdoMzJxcWJlbnpzaHJqMiJ9.tFlpAR14eZXbEzpDx03c5Q', {
    attribution: cartodbAttribution
}).addTo(map);

var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'rain-marker.png',
    iconSize: [32, 37],
    iconAnchor: [16, 37],
    popupAnchor: [0, -28]
});

function WeatherFilter(feature, layer) {
  if(feature.properties.type === "Weather") return true;
}

var UOSensorsLayer = L.geoJSON(UOSensors.responseJSON, {filter: WeatherFilter})
    .eachLayer(function (layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
}).addTo(map);

map.setView({ lat: 54.96, lng: -1.61 }, 12);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble adding this to UOSensorsLayer in the code below." What specifically is the trouble? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I can only display the markers using the default leaflet blue marker.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in my case and work perfectly for me is this :

```
var UOSensorsLayer = L.geoJSON(UOSensors.responseJSON), {
    filter : [...],
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        // For each point we return a marker with settings we want
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon}).bindTooltip(tooltip).bindPopup(popup);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: With the above I'm getting a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function line 52 after pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {

Comment: A token is missing in your code. You can try http://www.jslint.com/ to help you find the missing token or you can post your code here and tell me if my function work properly after